# How to write a thread which continuously checks no of files inside a directory in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

How to write a thread which continuously checks no of files inside a directory.

Note that I am exporting files in a directory under diff-diff folders. My Req is to get the  running status[Count] of files got exported in folders[which is changing continuously as export progress] .

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write your own thread/infrastructure here. Instead, you should "plug" into the built-in "file watcher" infrastructure.

In other words: there is a whole framework already at your fingertips; you "only" need to create your own *WatchService*.

For details (and a full tutorial), turn to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).